# Sending Ctrl+A combination to an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) for angular end-to-end aka `e2e` testing.

In order to send keys to an element, I use:

```
element(by.model('myModel')).sendKeys('Test');
```

How can I send a combination of keys, like `Ctrl+A`?

---

I've searched through [protractor source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?p=1&q=sendKeys&ref=cmdform) at github, but haven't found a relevant example.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think it will look something like `sendKeys(protractor.key.CONTROL + 'a')`

Comment: You might found anything helpful in the webdriverjs documentation.

Comment: For those interested in handling `CONTROL` vs `COMMAND`: [Using cross-platform keyboard shortcuts in end-to-end testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's perfectly possible in Linux and Windows but [not in OSX](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/690)

```
var elm = element(by.model('myModel'));
elm.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"));
```

There is also a non-element variant:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('a').perform();
```

Comment: Yeah, I was experimenting with `protractor.Key.COMMAND` (on mac) after posting a question - could not make it work. Thanks for the answer and for the link.

Comment: Be careful with the non-element variant, as it will leave the CONTROL key pressed for future tests. So keyUp CONTROL before perform.

Answer (score 9):

If you use [protractor-hotkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-hotkeys), you can use simple hotkey strings (like those from angular-hotkeys) to trigger them in protractor tests.

So, this would become:

```
var hotkeys = require('protractor-hotkeys');
hotkeys.trigger('ctrl+a', { targetElement: element(by.model('myModel')) });
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that's an awesome idea! Thank you for making it happen - will certainly add it to the toolkit.

Comment: Would `protractor-hotkeys` implicitly handle the ctrl vs command on windows vs mac? (referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing))

Comment: I decided to not tackle that issue for the time being -- it's was too difficult to test in my current situation. I tested only the [most basic stuff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-hotkeys#testing) that I am certain will work cross platform. If you could [give me some feedback on how it works](https://github.com/Droogans/protractor-hotkeys/issues), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Cool! please let us know if you decide to tacke Mac vs non-osx issues, even a warn.log would help so at least we know something will not work the same way cross platform ;)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like an old post. But Just sharing a solution worked for me to clear content of Tinymce editor using protractor in MAC.

```
var body_editor = element(by.id('tinymce'));/*id of body inside iframe*/
body_editor.click().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.COMMAND, "a"));
body_editor.click().sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
```

Comment: Hey @user2895098 what versions of Protractor / selenium are you using?

Comment: And what versions are you on @nwinkler ?

Comment: Tested it using Protractor 1.8.0 on Chrome, Mac OS X 10.10.2