# Copy and Paste in protractor js for e2e testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

Testing a webpage which has an area for pasting out a tab separated text by using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keys only (There is no textarea or any input field),
it is just a field where I can select the field by mouse click and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which automatically take all the text in the buffer.

So I get the Part of PASTING the text using the sendKeys for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, eg:
[Sending Ctrl+A combination to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300034/sending-ctrla-combination-to-an-element)

```
var elm = element(by.model('myModel'));
elm.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v"));
```

I am STUCK at COPYING. How to copy?

Is there a way I can store the tab separated text in

```
var String =[col1   col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
row1 1  2   3   4   5   6
row2 7  8   9   10  11  12
row3 13 14  15  16  17  18
];
```

and then paste it using a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> command to paste it,
on a Windows machine <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is explained here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Lets say the HTML is

```
 <input ng-paste="paste=true" ng-init="paste=false" placeholder='paste here'>
pasted: {{paste}}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can approach it without using the copy/paste shortcuts. Is it a public site and you can provide a link? Or, if not possible, show the HTML representation of the target element.

Comment: it not a public site, but let me try to find an example, 
lets say the HTML is this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPaste

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain me what do you want to do step-by-step, using the provided link? Would definitely help to help.

Comment: I want to copy a tab separated text from my MS Excel into the pasting area provided, So normally I would use CTRL+C in the MS Excel and on the website after click the input are would do CTRL+V to paste it. 

In portractor how do I perform CTRL+C COPY(not talking about the code for sendKeys CTRL+C).

Comment: I can think of the easier way to do,  copying the tab separated text before launching the protractor tests. once the tests launches it will have CTRL+V text on Windows buffer or any other OS's buffer

Comment: Though this wouldn't work if I had multiple things to be  copied and pasted .

Comment: Got answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750447/performing-a-copy-and-paste-with-selenium-2) and [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1037)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a dependency presented as a manual copying a text from an Excel File and having it in the buffer, parse the data source `excel` file(s) via one of the nodejs excel parsers:

- [`excel-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-parser)
- [`node-xlsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx)
- something else?

In this case you'll have the data available as a text in your test(s) and you would use the regular `sendKeys()` method on the element.