# Send combination keys to the browser

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor

I am having trouble trying to send Shift and then immediately tilde (~).
I have tried several examples, here is one that I am trying.
In the system - I am trying to test the next scenario -
I need to choose a certain image, and then send shift ~  -> insert certain number, shift 3

shift 3 for example is an immediate action, can't wait between those two.
Same for shift ~

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(imagePicked).perform();
         await imagePicked.click();
         await browser.actions().sendKeys(((protractor.Key.SHIFT,"~"))).perform();
         await browser.actions().sendKeys(barcode).perform();
         await browser.actions().sendKeys(((protractor.Key.SHIFT,"3"))).perform();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300034/sending-ctrla-combination-to-an-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, this helped me :

```
      await imagePicked.click();
     await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT,('~')).keyUp(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform();
     await browser.actions().sendKeys(barcode).perform();
     await browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT).sendKeys('3').keyUp(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform();
```

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and if this still do not resolves your case, you can share stack trace or error message.
`browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT).sendKeys('~').perform();`

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help me .it seems that it's not clicking those buttons.